# A specific group lacking Følner sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

How does one go about proving that the free group $<a,b,a^{-1},b^{-1}>$ lacks any Følner sequence?

Comment: I think it's easiest to show $F_2$ is not amenable by exhibiting a paradoxical decomposition, rather than working directly with Følner sets.

Comment: What do  $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ mean here? Usually one puts the generators first, and then the relations, if any, so are all of $a,b,a^{-1},b^{-1}$ considered to be free generators? [what confuses me is that in a free group one would automatically consider an inverse of a generator to be included without mentioning it]

Comment: @coffeemath, I agree.  I just mean $<a,b>$ without any relations that are not imposed/guaranteed by the group axioms.  My math professor wrote it as presented above though. It is just the set of all reduced words over alphabet $\{a,b\}$ endowed with a group operator.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip, I am not familiar with any of that terminology, so a more detailed explanation would be nice. My professor randomly assigned this question (it is off-topic to the class and we have not covered anything like/about this at all).  It is not really homework, just a "you should look into this" sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to sketch the standard proof, but it actually has a sticky technical point, so I'm not sure how satisfying you will find it.

First, a group $G$ is said to be amenable if it has a finitely additive, left-invariant probability measure. That is, there is a function $\mu\colon \mathcal P(G)\to [0,1]$ such that $\mu(G)=1$, $\mu(X\amalg Y)=\mu(X)+\mu(Y)$, and for all $g\in G$, $\mu(X)=\mu(gX)$. (Here $X \amalg Y$ is the union of $X,Y$ assuming they are disjoint.)

Now if a group has a Følner sequence $F_i$, you can define
$$\mu(X)=\operatorname{ulim}_{i\to \infty} \frac{|X\cap F_i|}{|F_i|}.$$
The fancy $\operatorname{ulim}_{i\to\infty}$ is the *ultrafilter limit*, and is a way to force limits to exist even when they don't. (This is that sticky technical point.) You can verify that $\mu$ is a finitely additive probability measure. See [Wikipedia's article on Følner sequences.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B8lner_sequence) So in other words, the existence of a Følner sequence implies amenability.

But now, we can also show that $\langle a,b\rangle$ has no such probabilty measure. Let $W(\alpha)$ be the set of reduced words beginning with $\alpha$. Then
\begin{align*}
\langle a,b\rangle &=\{1\}\amalg W(a)\amalg W(a^{-1})\amalg W(b)\amalg W(b^{-1})\\
&=W(a)\amalg aW(a^{-1})\\
&=W(b)\amalg bW(b^{-1})
\end{align*}
Applying $\mu$ gives a contradiction, since the latter two equations give that $\mu(W(a)\amalg aW(a^{-1}))=\mu(W(b)\amalg bW(b^{-1}))=1$, and then the first equation gives
$1=\mu(\{1\})+2$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you.  I am going to try to process all of that. I may come back occasionally with further questions, but I appreciate the work that you have done already.

Comment: Sure, no problem.